# A good UI Unit Testing solution suitable for ASP.NET development (browser UI compatible)?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, tdd

does anyone know of a good automated UI Unit Testing solution suitable for ASP.NET development (Browser UI compatible)?

Would be interested in learning it if so. NUnit integration / compatibility would be a bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSTest - Part of Visual Studio 2008 Test Edition and Ultimate.  Also part of Visual Studio 2010 Premium and Ultimate.  Supports easy recording and playback, stable but has a learning code for manual test code editing.

Selenium - As suggested earlier.  Surprisingly well done, especially in Firefox.  Open-sourced, written in Java. Recorder is a Firefox plugin only and we never got recorded tests to work with IE.  That was a problem for us because the test creators weren't coders so had to rely on recording tests.  But there is a major version about to be released.

[Watin](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) - Open source.  Written in C#.  Less development than Salenium but still has a solid list of features.

Comment: Thanks for this. Checked answer because an open source C# solution seems like a good way to go for .net development. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

We use selenium and are happy with it.  It supports nUnit.  Here is a good [write up](http://devio.wordpress.com/2008/09/30/automated-web-application-testing-using-selenium-and-nunit/)

It does not support silverlight which is a downside for us.